# How to write functions when type of values are different?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, typeof

I have a problem with making my function smarter. I achieve good results, but I think about the other solution.

I can take `boolean` or `object` as parameter. When the parameter is the `object` I'd like to keep it as now. When the parameter is a `boolean` value, I'd like to create an object, where keys are taken from another variable (less important) and values are this `boolean`.

My solution assumes

- adding an empty items object at the beginning
- reading what is a value  type and setting items according to the conditions
- taking items and converting to an array
- saving the array in state

Is that OK?

Check my code

```
const onAddAll = value => {
        let items = {}

        if (typeof value === 'boolean') {
            terms.forEach(term => items[ term ] = value)
        }

        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            items = value
        }

        const checked = Object.keys(items).filter(k => items[ k ])
        setChecked(checked)
    }
```

Imo, I wouldn't need the second condition and make it smarter, bot no idea how. Please help!

I use it here

```
<Checkbox
  items={getItems()}
  onChange={onAddAll}
>
  <label className="sr-only">
    {i18n.t('DROPDOWN.SELECT_ALL')}
  </label>
</Checkbox>
```

and here

```
<Dropdown>
  {[ 'all', 'none' ].map((key, i) => (
    <li key={key}
      className="dropdown__item">
      <div className="dropdown__link"
        onClick={onAddAll.bind(this, !i)}>                               
        {i18n.t(`DROPDOWN.${key.toUpperCase()}`)}
      </div>
    </li>
  ))}
</Dropdown>
```

Comment: Where is your function called? Maybe your code can be smarter by changing way you call it (always pass an object by doing what you do in the first if statement before calling the function

Comment: I agree with @thchpp, you shouldn't have a method that takes 2 different types of parameter, so you should create your object in another method when your param is a boolean, then call your `onAddAll` method

Comment: Make an object like `lookup = {boolean : booleanFn, object: objectFn}` then invoke it like `lookup[typeof value]()`.

Comment: I made the update in description! Please have a look!